# Copy installed packages using pip to another environment

Tags: python

I downloaded some packages in my environment using pip command. And I want to have a copy of them to transfer them to another environment. I know that using:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

will generate requirements into a file, but since my second environment does not have access to internet i can not use:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

to install that packages again.
Is there any way to copy installed packages? or somehow install packages in a specified directory in my first environment?
Thanks

Comment: [pipdeptree](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) is great for determining what packages *you* installed (without listing the dependencies).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use pip [download](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/) followed by pip install [--find-links](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#find-links) to achieve what you want.Here is the steps involved

1. Get the requirements

> pip freeze>requirements.txt

2. Download the packages to a folder

> ```
> pip download -r requirements.txt -d path_to_the_folder
> ```

3. From the new environment

> pip install -r requirements.txt --find-links=path_to_the_folder

Comment: I had to add `--no-index` to make it work offline:

`pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links=path_to_the_folder`.

Without it, pip still tries to connect to the internet, as per [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#finding-packages) - "pip looks for packages in a number of places: on PyPI (if not disabled via --no-index), in the local filesystem, and in any additional repositories specified via --find-links or --index-url."

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @Jose Cherians Post:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/49333415/22502105

Instead of `pip freeze>requirements.txt` you can use pipreqs:

1. `pip install pipreqs`
2. `pipreqs AbsolutePathOfProject`

It will generate the `requirements.txt` in the project path.
Next just follow step 2 and 3 from Jose.

This will generate only the needed reqs not the whole python libraries you already got from your python version. Normally you have a working python installation even on the offline systems. Then you just can add the imports like you would do via package manager.