# How to install package into an environment from another environment?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

Say I have a `virtualenv` environment `myenv1` and another, `myenv2`. I have some packages installed in `myenv1`, and I would like to install them on `myenv2` as well. Is there a way to install them in `myenv2` using `myenv1`?

I referred to the [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333152/copy-installed-packages-using-pip-to-another-environment), but apparently that requires a `requirement.txt` to be present.

However, I have installed many packages on the go, and I do not have a prepared `requirement.txt` for `myenv1`. Also, the second step requires **downloading the required packages again** to a folder. Is there a way to achieve the said without downloading anything again?

Comment: did you try to follow the steps from the linked question's answer? `pip install` won't delete any packages you have already installed in myenv2

Comment: I just want a couple of packages, and so I'm refraining from the said approach.

Comment: well, you could also edit the requirements.txt before calling for the download / install?

Comment: The second step in the link still requires downloading the packages again. I wonder if there was a workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

[pipdeptree](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) is great for determining what packages *you* installed and to bring over to a new environment.

The docs demonstrate how you can generate a requirements file that only contains the packages you installed (and not their dependencies):

```
pipdeptree --freeze --warn silence | grep -E '^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+' > requirements.txt
```

You could then pare down that requirements file to only the packages you *really* need and then follow the `pip download` steps. That would minimize your download.

---

If you don't want to download any packages again, you could try using [pip's cache directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41111916/79125):

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --find-links=%LocalAppData%\pip\cache\wheels
```

However, I don't know how long pip's caching strategy would keep old installed packages around. Read more [on pip's Caching docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/caching/). Maybe you could `pip download --find-links` to to pull out the cached packages and then `pip download` to get the rest?